# Arcpy Reclassify by Standard Deviation

Tags: arcpy, raster, spatial-analyst, reclassify

I would need some help with the Reclassify tool. I have written a script that produces rasters which I need to reclassify. My problem is, I want the values to be reclassified by standard deviation which I don't know how to do. I would like to make two new classes:

values < mean + 2 * standard deviation

values >= mean + 2 * standard deviation

I need help with putting this into a script.

Answer (score 2):

Begin by loading your raster.

```
rast = arcpy.sa.Raster(pathtorasterfile)
```

Find the mean, standard deviations, minimum and maximum:

```
meanValue = rast.mean
std = rast.standardDeviation
minR = rast.minimum - .1 #just a little buffer room
maxR = rast.maximum + .1 #just a little buffer room
```

Setup the bounds:

```
target = meanValue + (2*std)
```

Create a remaprange object:

```
remapRangeValues = arcpy.sa.RemapRange([[minR,target-.00001,0],[target,maxR,1]])
```

Reclassify and save the new raster:

```
outReclass = arcpy.sa.Reclassify(rast, "VALUE", remapRangeValues)
outReclass.save(reclassifiedname)
```

I didn't test this, and I wasn't sure what you wanted to reclassify the values as. You may change the 0 or 1 in the RemapRange object to get the values you want.

Comment: Do you mean `minR = rast.minimum - .1`?

Comment: Thank you! The problem with this is that RemapRange does not seem to take in variables, only actual values which I cannot hard code because I have a set of rasters and they all have different values.

Comment: That's strange. I use it with variables in tools where I don't know what the values will be. Could you edit your question and post your existing code for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
import arcpy
```

Set the workspace to the folder where you have your data

```
arcpy.env.workspace="Path:\to\your\data\"  
for raster in arcpy.ListRasters():
```

Create an object storing the st. dev. for the raster file:

```
    stdev_object=arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(raster, "STD")
```

Store the numeric value of st. dev. in the variable `stdev` :

```
    stdev=stdev_object.getOutput[0]
```

Same thing for mean value:

```
    mean_object=arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(raster, "MEAN")
    mean=mean.getOutput[0]
    threshold=mean + 2* stdev
```

You can use Raster Calculator for this instead of Reclassify:

```
    Output_raster="some\path\and\name\for\output\raster"
    expression="Con(" + raster + "<=" + str(threshold) + ",1,2"
```

The string 
    resulting from the above concatenation is an expression that tells Raster Calculator: 
    if a raster cell value is <= than threshold change
       that value to 1, else change it to 2 (you can of course any values you like).

Now we actually reclassify the raster:

```
    arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa(expression, Output_raster)
```

Done!

This works if you have your rasters in a ArcGIS native format, otherwise you need to convert them first. More info here:
[Get Raster Properties tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/get-raster-properties.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your raster to a numpy Array, then use numpy.where and convert back to raster:

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np

rasterfile = r"C:\GIS\data\DEM50m\grid50m\nh_63_4.tif"
new_raster = r"C:\GIS\data\DEM50m\grid50m\nh_63_4_reclassed.tif"

arr = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(rasterfile)
arr = np.where(arr<arr.mean()+2*arr.std(), 1, 2)

newarr = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(in_array=arr, lower_left_corner=r.extent.lowerLeft, x_cell_size=r.meanCellWidth, y_cell_size=r.meanCellHeight)
newarr.save(new_raster)
```

[image]